# How reset existing sql server connection in excel workbook

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have created an Excel workbook with SQL server connection and loaded data using SQL commands. I want to use the same excel file in a different machine, there I want to change the database credentials. In our excel file, there are more than 10  SQL server connections and sheets, So recreate the file is very difficult. Is there any way to reuse the file with a different database?

I have copied the excel file with all .odc files, But I couldn't find an option to reset the connection to the new database.

Comment: Which Excel Version?

Comment: Excel file created using Excel 2013 and trying to open in Excel 2010

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities:

1. Edit the ODC files manually with a text editor
2. In Excel, use "Data" -> "Connections" to edit the connections

Comment: Have you tried to edit the ODC files manually, i.e. with a text editor?